# Rails add a second field name to validation error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

`rails 5.2`, `ruby 2.6.4`

A `Student` record has these fields, in part:

```
fname,
lname,
emplid,
class_code,
...
```

The class_code is a digit 1,2,3,4.

```
1 = freshman
2 = sophomore
3 = junior
4 = senior
```

I have a validation:

```
validates_inclusion_of :class_code, :in => Constants::CLASS_CODES,    
    message: "The class code, %{value}, is not considered a valid class code."
```

This works, but it would be very helpful if I could tell which student record this error happens on.  I would like to add the field `emplid` to the error message.  Is this possible?

Something like:

```
message: "For student {emplid}, %{value} is not considered a valid class code."
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a lambda to `message`.

```
validates_inclusion_of :class_code, :in => Constants::CLASS_CODES,
  message: ->(student, options) { "For student #{student.emplid}, #{options[:value]} is not considered a valid class code." }
```